# WxHaskell and DragAndDrop: how to create custom event to trigger dropTargetOnData, dropTargetOnDrop, dropTargetOnEnter, dropTargetOnDragOver

Tags: haskell, wxpython, wxhaskell, reactive-banana

## WxHaskell and DragAndDrop

I would like to know how to use the following events handlers
 : dropTargetOnData, dropTargetOnDrop, dropTargetOnEnter, dropTargetOnDragOver….[1]

Could you check if my current believes are corrects :

- From wx Widgets/ wxPython [2] /  [3] /  [4] it looks like they need to be used to manage DragAndDrog for non trivial examples.
- they are not actionable via an existing event like "on drag", etc..
- I tried and create my own event.  but it does not get "activated". [7]
- besides, from the signatures [1], these look like being activated on DropTarget, unlike other events on Reactive/ Windows/Controls . Is It Correct ?
- Heinrich created its own events "onText", (in reactive-Banana) but this is on a Control. [6]
- Could someone confirm these events effectively worked for them in WxHaskell, and maybe hint how to do that

  [1]: 

  `from Graphics.UI.WXCore.Events , line 1933 onwards`

  Set an event handler that is called when the drop target can be filled with data.
   This function require to use 'dropTargetGetData' in your event handler to fill data.
  dropTargetOnData :: DropTarget a -> (Point -> DragResult -> IO DragResult) -> IO ()
  ...

  -- | Set an event handler for an drop command in a drop target.
  dropTargetOnDrop :: DropTarget a -> (Point -> IO Bool) -> IO ()

  -- | Set an event handler for an enter command in a drop target.
  dropTargetOnEnter :: DropTarget a -> (Point -> DragResult -> IO DragResult) -> IO ()

  -- | Set an event handler for a drag over command in a drop target.
  dropTargetOnDragOver :: DropTarget a -> (Point -> DragResult -> IO DragResult) -> IO ()

  -- | Set an event handler for a leave command in a drop target.
  dropTargetOnLeave :: DropTarget a -> (IO ()) -> IO ()

[2] : http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_wxdroptarget.html#wxdroptargetondrop

[3] : http://wiki.wxpython.org/DragAndDrop

[4] : http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/06/20/wxpython-introduction-to-drag-and-drop/

[5] : http://wewantarock.wordpress.com/2011/06/17/how-does-wxhaskell-event-handling-work-part-1/

[6] : https://github.com/HeinrichApfelmus/reactive-banana/blob/master/reactive-banana-wx/src/Reactive/Banana/WX.hs  L 88

[7] : 

    `module Main where`

```
import Graphics.UI.WX hiding (empty)

import Data.Maybe
import Control.Monad
import Graphics.UI.WX.Events
import Graphics.UI.WXCore.WxcClassesMZ
--import Graphics.UI.WXCore.WxcClassesAL
import Graphics.UI.WXCore.DragAndDrop
import Graphics.UI.WXCore.Events   
main
  = start dndtest
dndtest
  = do
      f      <- frame  [text := "Drag And Drop test"]
      p      <- panel  f []
      ok     <- button p [text := "Ok"]
      xinput <- textEntry p [text := "here :"] --textEntry
      yinput <- staticText p [text := "drag me"]
      zinput <- staticText p [text := "result me"]

      set f [defaultButton := ok
             ,layout := container p $
                        margin 10 $
                        column 5 [boxed "coordinates" (grid 5 5 [[label "source:", hfill $ widget yinput]
                                                                ,[label "target(focus first):", hfill $ widget xinput]
                                                                ,[label "result:", hfill $ widget zinput]
                                                                ])
                                 ,floatBottomRight $ row 5 [widget ok]]
                                 ]

      set xinput [ on enter := onEnter]

      set yinput [ ]

---------------------------------------------------------
--- meaningful stuff starts here
---------------------------------------------------------

       -- prepare the drop source : create a DataObject and associate it with the source
      textdata' <- textDataObjectCreate "text dropped"
      src <- dropSource textdata' yinput



       -- prepare the drop target: create a DataObject (placeholder here) and associate it with the target
      textdata <- textDataObjectCreate ".."
      drop <- dropTarget xinput textdata
      set drop [ on onMyDrop := showMeDrop ]  ---- <<<< I am expecting this to get fired but no ...
      -- obj create a new event on drop invoking ..
      -- and see if it is invoked

      set yinput [ on drag := onDrag src ]
      set xinput [ ] ------ <<<< I am expecting the target to react when dropped  (Its DroopedTarget i fact)
      set zinput [ on mouse := showMeE]


      set ok [ on command := close f ]
      return ()

--- this is the custom event, just a setter to fire dropTargetOnDrop. not sure at all this is the correct way.

onMyDrop = newEvent "onmyDrop" (\w -> ioError (userError ("attribute '" ++ "onmyDrop" ++ "' is write-only.")))  dropTargetOnDrop
--dropTargetOnDrop :: DropTarget a -> (Point -> IO Bool) -> IO ()
--- the rest are jsut helper to see whats going on

showMeEo = putStr "showMeEo"
showMeDrop p = do
                putStr "showMeDrop"
                return True



onDrag s p  =  do

--    dragAndDrop :: DropSource a -> DragMode -> (DragResult -> IO ()) -> IO ()
    dragAndDrop s Default (\r -> do {putStr "DnD handler called: "; putStrLn(show r); return ()})
    putStrLn "on Drag activated:"



showMeE :: EventMouse -> IO ()
showMeE (MouseMotion point mod) = putStr ""  --- discard meaningless Motion event
showMeE  e = putStrLn $ show e

--
onEnter p = putStrLn $ "on Enter:" ++ show p
```